# What are the customs for incorporating other answers into your own?

Tags: discussion, answers

I'm new to SE as a contributor. In [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/77671/28034) I didn't initially think about the time to relay information to other players, but several other people pointed it out, so I added a note to my answer as well, in hopes of making a better complete answer. I *think* that's consistent with what I've read about making answers stand on their own, but I've also seen complaints about copying answers.

Q: Did I do the right thing according to community standards? Should I have included some form of attribution, like "as others have said" or "as Name pointed out"? And would your answer change if the amount I copied was larger or smaller?

Answer (score 11):

Stack Exchange is basically a big made-up game that drives people to compete or collaborate to provide the *best* possible answer to any question the site accepts. That *also* means the most complete answer, as [every answer should independently fully answer the question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3326/should-i-be-requesting-people-answer-the-question-independently). This encourages [absorbing material left sitting around in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3571/what-should-i-do-if-the-most-valuable-response-came-in-a-comment-rather-than-an/3572#3572). Absorbing material from other answers [is also fair game](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4837/1204): you're making a more complete and helpful answer, good job. On principle, everything's fine here.

Here's the rub: *don't half-arse it.* That's why you're feeling like you did something wrong. If you just add an inferior summary of another answer, your answer will look inferior and half-arsed, and you'll just be making the other answer look good by comparison. **Don't update your answer just to [keep up with the Joneses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keeping_up_with_the_Joneses). If you're going to cover new material in your answer, make a *stellar* treatment of it that you can be proud of, and that we can be grateful you contributed.** Beat the other answer by a league. If you don't, you're probably just dragging your answer down, and you won't be winning the made-up game.

You'll feel better for putting your whole heart and soul into making that amendment *awesome.* You'll feel okay for leaving your answer as-is.

Now, for crediting other users: that's only *required* when you're obviously using their work, because you're falling into the terms of our site's CC-BY-SA license. Otherwise, it's discretionary. Provide it if you feel like they deserve it. [Make it short and snappy and out of the way](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3430/when-is-it-proper-to-thank-another-user/3431#3431). As a rule of thumb, if you're legally obligated to cite someone else under CC-BY-SA, you probably half-arsed it. If you did a really good job, you might want to thank someone for putting you onto it anyway, because you can stand proud that you worked hard [and defer to the people who helped you get there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_on_the_shoulders_of_giants) without feeling like a cheapskate.

---

Also obligatory (not that you did this, good job): [Don't signal your edits in text](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/dont-signal-your-edits-in-text). If you're going to update your answer to cover more stuff, don't include an **Update:** section. That's being lazy. Revise your answer so that the update is just a natural part of it. It'll look better and flow better, and there'll probably be other parts of your answer that'll be more awesome for it.

Comment: Actually, I was pretty confident that my treatment of the idea was as good as anyone else's - more succinct and with a better citation - but if it looks half-assed to you, let me know how I can improve it! Thanks for the otherwise helpful answer + links, though.

Comment: The flip side of this is, [partial answers are better than nothing](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and can be built on to crowdsource a solution: "Help us find a solution by researching the problem, then contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a partial answer. That way, even if we can’t figure it out, the next person has more to go on."

Comment: @BESW that gives me pause for thought about the fully answering the question meta.

Comment: @SirTechSpec I don't know enough to judge those D&D 5e answers, not being someone who has played that game. If you feel like you did a good job, well, good job. ;) I'll edit later to have this not make that assumption.

Comment: @doppelgreener You may find it helpful to think about it in the context of an alternative to answers-in-comments.